# What am i doing wrong? Add text to bar chart with d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Have the following code to show a bar graph. I am trying to show the value on a text label. The things is that the element is created but is not showing the value.

Here is the code:

```
var data =[{"Anio":"1998","EJF":"50726","EXP":"0","RDC":"0","Total":"50726"},     {"Anio":"1999","EJF":"6403","EXP":"0","RDC":"0","Total":"6403"},{"Anio":"2000","EJF":"59211","EXP":"417","RDC":"0","Total":"59628"},{"Anio":"2001","EJF":"153053","EXP":"2801","RDC":"0","Total":"155854"},{"Anio":"2002","EJF":"68500","EXP":"2768","RDC":"0","Total":"71268"},{"Anio":"2003","EJF":"85650","EXP":"4658","RDC":"0","Total":"90308"},{"Anio":"2004","EJF":"70980","EXP":"4689","RDC":"0","Total":"75669"},{"Anio":"2005","EJF":"32670","EXP":"5889","RDC":"0","Total":"38559"},{"Anio":"2006","EJF":"78843","EXP":"5822","RDC":"0","Total":"84665"},{"Anio":"2007","EJF":"3771","EXP":"4925","RDC":"322","Total":"8696"},{"Anio":"2008","EJF":"82869","EXP":"5501","RDC":"342","Total":"88370"},{"Anio":"2009","EJF":"55795","EXP":"4148","RDC":"349","Total":"59943"},{"Anio":"2010","EJF":"54755","EXP":"4261","RDC":"341","Total":"59016"},{"Anio":"2011","EJF":"83147","EXP":"4000","RDC":"301","Total":"87147"},{"Anio":"2012","EJF":"27939","EXP":"3251","RDC":"248","Total":"31190"},{"Anio":"2013","EJF":"89643","EXP":"4385","RDC":"240","Total":"94028"},{"Anio":"2014","EJF":"53832","EXP":"3993","RDC":"688","Total":"58513"}];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 860 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(arr_data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(arr_data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

 chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

chart.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(arr_data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("fill","#632423")
  .on('mouseover',function(d){
      var a = d3.select(this)
      .attr("fill","#733A39");

  }).on('mouseout',function(d){
      var a = d3.select(this)
      .attr("fill","#632423"); //old color: #790018        
  });

  chart.selectAll(".bar")
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value)+16; })
  .style("stroke", 'white');
```

I dont know why is that, if someone could show me some light...thanks!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're appending the `text` elements to the `rect` elements, which won't work. Group both with `g` elements, see [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I add a G (group) element, the code looks like this:

```
var chart = d3.select(".chart")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(arr_data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(arr_data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

var bar = chart.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(arr_data)
.enter().append("g");

bar.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("fill","#632423")
  .on('mouseover',function(d){
      var a = d3.select(this)
      .attr("fill","#733A39");

    var a = d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left","100px")
    .style("top","20px")
    .select("#value")
    .text(d.value);

  }).on('mouseout',function(d){
      var a = d3.select(this)
      .attr("fill","#632423"); //old color: #790018        
  });

  bar.append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name)+4; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value)+20 ; });
```